# Iptables subnet

Tags: iptables, subnet

I have an iptable rule where I allow a subnet of IPs. The rule is as the following:

iptables -I INPUT 2 -i eth0 -s x.x.x.x/24 -d x.x.X.x -j ACCEPT

For example, I want to allow subnet 172.16.0.0/24. May I face up with a problem like an IP from this subnet has no access, although I have configured this subnet to be allowed?

I am dealing with an issue like this. I have configured 172.16.0.0/24 to allowed from iptables but when I try to access from IP 172.16.0.9, I have no access.

Comment: Can you update your question with the output for `iptables-save` ?

Comment: After I ran iptables-save, I ran iptables -n -v -L --line-numbers and from the output, there is a line with the allowed subnet I added. However, I have a few matches.

Comment: I've asked for the output of `iptables-save` because maybe you have another rule that overrides the one you talk about in your question...Are you able to access from another ip than 172.16.0.9 but in same subnet 172.16.0.0/24 ?

Comment: I think of another rule that may overwrite that rule I have recently added. But, nothing like that happens. I can access from some IPs but not from all IPs of the subent.

Comment: Did you try `tcpdump` at firewall side to check for incoming packets from 172.16.0.9 ?

Comment: Can you update your question with the output for iptables-save ?

Comment: I'll repeat what others have said here: Please edit your question and add the output of `iptables-save`. Without seeing the entirety of your iptables rules, we're groping in the dark...

Answer (score 2):

You can debug netfilter rules by enabling the TRACE target:

First load the relevant kernel module to log directly to syslog:

```
modprobe -i ipt_LOG
```

And then create a rule to log all traffic from your misbehaving system:

```
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING --source 172.16.0.9 -p tcp -j TRACE
```

The packets are  logged  with   the   string   prefix:   `TRACE:   tablename:chain-
name:type:rulenum` where type can be "rule" for plain rule, "return' for implicit rule at the end of a user defined chain and  "policy"  for the policy of the built in chains.
The rulenum can be found with `iptables -L --line-numbers`

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove "-d x.x.x.x". I say this because INPUT means all traffic destined to your machine, so no need to specify destination.
EDIT:  Also, try to add "-p tcp" before "-s x.x.x.x/24". I think you need to specify the protocol for the match. –  aseaudi 17 mins ago

Comment: I tried this. The problem remians.

Comment: Ok, now try to add "-p tcp" before "-s x.x.x.x/24". I think you need to specify the protocol for the match.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking about two possible issues:

1 - you are not allowing the traffic to go out from your machine

```
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -i eth0 -d x.x.x.x/24 -j ACCEPT
```

2 - you are preventing broadcast packets from getting to your machine

try this instead of your original input:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i eth0 -s x.x.x.x/24 -j ACCEPT
```

without using a destination ip.